# MongoDB function like effected rows in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, mongodb, pdo

I am new at MongoDB and I want to proof if the result of my query is the expected. Like the effected rows or something in SQL. I am working in PHP with pdo and mongoDB.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something like this:

```
$result->count()
```

This gave me the effected rows of a query in mongodb.
Just for your information

Comment: Please do not include closings, emoticons, or signatures in your posts. Your user box includes your 'signature', and closings/emoticons only make searches more difficult.